# Magento WYSIWYG editor image upload not working

Tags: magento-1.7, image, wysiwyg

Hello Everyone
I have a problem with my WYSIWYG editor in magento admin. When I try to upload image or video, it processes the image. Then shows 100% upload complete message. After that nothing happens. The image is not uploaded and it doesn't show in the list.
I have no idea how this happened. It was working before but now it just doesn't.
I don't know what caused the problem or how to solve this. Does anyone have any idea??
Thanks in Advance.

Comment: You've checked that the permissions haven't been changed on the media directory, right?

Comment: I have again made sure that the permissions are set. It is 777 for media folder as well as for wysiwyg folder in it.

Comment: I've experienced this issue previously but can't remember what I did to fix it now. Can you test in a different browser and see if any different?

Comment: Hello Geoff, I have tested it in other browsers but result is the same. I also have replaced the js folder with a fresh magento copy js folder. But no success.. :(

Comment: any errors in `var/log`?

Comment: No. There is nothing in log files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix function `getDirsCollection($path)` in file `Mage\Cms\Model\Wysiwyg\Images\Storage.php`.
 and repair `function getStorageRoot()` in `Mage\Cms\Helper\Wysiwyg\Images.php`

1.

```
Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config -> add lines: const IMAGE_DIRECTORY = 'wysiwyg';
```

2.

```
public function getStorageRoot()
    {
        return Mage::getConfig()->getOptions()->getMediaDir() . DS . Mage_Cms_Model_Wysiwyg_Config::IMAGE_DIRECTORY . DS;
    }
```

3.

```
public function getDirsCollection($path)
    {
        if (Mage::helper('core/file_storage_database')->checkDbUsage()) {
            $subDirectories = Mage::getModel('core/file_storage_directory_database')->getSubdirectories($path);
            foreach ($subDirectories as $directory) {
                $fullPath = rtrim($path, DS) . DS . $directory['name'];
                  if (!file_exists($fullPath)) {
                    mkdir($fullPath, 0777, true);
                }
            }
        }
...

}
```

Comment: Can you explain what the problem is you are fixing?

Answer (score 0):

check you browser error logs for errors.

The File upload uses flash, maybe it is causing the error somehow.
mod_secutiy (Apache webserver) could also cause some problems. Check you werbserver's error log.